# ​Keeping empty values as empty in a dataframe while doing a operation using udf

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

I have a dataframe which has empty values for one of the column.

I m passing the column to a udf for doing a mathematical multiplication. I want to skip that udf for values which are empty. I don't want use na.fill to replace the empty.

Schema of my DF looks like 
DataFrame1

```
root
|-- Name: string (nullable =true)
|-- Value: decimal(38,0) (nullable=true) //This is the col
|-- powValue: integer (nullable=true)
|-- mulValue: integer (nullable=true)
```

```
def udfFn(val1: Integer, powVal:Integer, mulVal:Integer) = {
val bd1 = new BigDecimal(val1);
val bd2 =bd1.scakeByPowerTen(-powVal)

val bd3 = new BigDecimal(mulVal)
val bd4=bd2.multiply(bd3)
}
val calUDF=udf({(val1: Integer, powVal:Integer, mulVal:Integer)=> 
udfFn(val1,powVal,mulVal)})

val newDf=DataFrame1.withColumn("Final_Value",calUDF(col("Value"),col("powValue"),col("mulValue")))
```

My **DataFrame1** can contain 0,empty,Numerics in the column **Value**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like `val1` and `Value` actually should be `BigDecimal` based on the type being `decimal(38,0)` so I am going to make that assumption in the code below.

The quick way to do this would just be to use a good 'ole `if-else` statement. This might also be the most performant way depending:

```
def udfFn(val1: BigDecimal, powVal: Int, mulVal: Int): BigDecimal =
  if (val1 != null && powVal != null && mulVal != null) {
    val mul = new BigDecimal(mulVal)
    val1.scaleByPowerTen(-powVal).multiply(mul)
  } else {
    null
  }
```

I think this looks a bit ugly myself, if you want to make it nicer reading, it's a job for functional programming! `Option` and `for` comprehensions to the rescue! (Note that if performance is an issue, this first solution may be your best option)

You could do the following:

```
def udfFn(val1: BigDecimal, powVal: Int, mulVal: Int): Option[BigDecimal] =
  val r = for {
    bd1 <- Option(val1)
    pow <- Option(powVal)
    mul <- Option(mulVal).map(new BigDecimal(_))
  } yield (bd1.scaleByPowerTen(-pow).multiply(mul))
```

The `for` comprehension will yield an `Option` that is `Some` only if every input `Option` is `Some` otherwise it will be `None`.

My personal preference would be to do this with `Dataset` instead of `DataFrame`, as I think it makes the transformations easier to understand and makes the schema pretty explicit at each step as well as allowing you to write transformations without relying on UDFs, but it's definitely best to do whatever you and/or your organization are more comfortable with. For a `Dataset` solution I would make a couple of case classes:

```
case class NewData(name: Option[String], val1: Option[BigDecimal], powVal: Option[Int], mulVal: Option[Int], finalValue: Option[BigDecimal])

case class SomeData(name: Option[String], val1: Option[BigDecimal], powVal: Option[Int], mulVal: Option[Int]) {
  def toNewData: NewData = {
    val fv = for {
      bd1 <- val1
      pow <- powVal
      mul <- mulVal.map(new BigDecimal(_))
    } yield (bd1.scaleByPowerTen(-pow).multiply(mul))

    NewData(name, val1, powVal, mulVal, fv)
  }
}
```

Then the code to do the transformation would be this:

```
import spark.implicits._

val ds: Dataset[SomeData] = ... // Obtained however you wish
val finalDs: Dataset[NewData] = ds.map(_.toNewData)
```

Comment: Thank you!! I am using String to take this Decimal(38,0) column (val1: Integer).